# How to deploy and install a new font in my customer server (Error: font is no available in JVM)

Tags: linux, maven, fonts, jvm, jasper-reports

When I try to download a Report from my WebClient I get an error from JasperReports (net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font "Arial" is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.).

I already know how to solve this issue locally, but, my "boss" asked me to input the font .ttf into the .war folder to, when I deploy the system in the customer server (Linux red hat), it automatically install the font in it.

I really don't know if it's possible. My idea is to enhance the maven install inscript, or another script that is used to deploy the application in customer server, to move the .ttf file from an "blablabla/etc/fonts" folder into the system fonts folder.

I already lost 1 day looking for an automated solution for it and didn't find anything. If anybody knows if there is an solution for it, please help me!

Thank you all.

Comment: Is your question "how to install artifact (*jar* with font) to maven repo"?

Comment: Did you try to use font extensions?

Comment: Hi @AlexK, my application server is based in JBoss so, I have the standard folder path, that is jboss-version/standalone/deployments. There in deployments I have my .war files, so, my question is about how to deploy my application with a new font using my .war folder as a source for this font. I don't know if i was clear in my question, but I think that use artifacts is not the solution, but I will read about font extensions, thank you.

Comment: You can pack font at jar (font extension) and use this jar at war. Are you using Maven?

Comment: Yes, I am. I think i got it! But, to JVM load this fonts, it should be with the system fonts or inside ~jdk/jre/lib/fonts. How do you sugest to put it inside these folders?

Comment: You don't need to put fonts at jre/jdk folder. You should use font extensions :)